# How to avoid copies with move

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to create a functor with parameters and call it in an accessor - I'm hoping that the compiler will optimize away the code for speed. Here is my attempt:

```
struct X {
  X(int a, float b) : _a(a), _b(b) {}
  float operator()(float value) const { /* do something */; }
  int _a;
  float _b;
};

struct Y {
  Y(const X&& x) : _x(move(x)) {}
  float operator()(float value) const { return _x(value); }
  const X&& _x;
};
```

which I call thus in an accessor of some Object of class `Value`:

```
float getValue() const {    
  X x(2, 3.14);
  Y y(move(x));
  return y(_value);
}
```

Is this the best way to code this, or can it be done in a simpler way?

Comment: `X` doesn't hold any resources, what is the point of using move semantics?

Comment: An rvalue reference member doesn't make sense. Also `Y` has no call operator as stated in the question, so what do you expect `y(_value)` to do?

Comment: Barry - yes - I haven't wrapped my head around this rvalue reference thing, coming C++98 and now discovering C++11... that's why I'm posting this. Note that the compiler doesn't complain at all.

Comment: try reading http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html, it explains them really well.

Comment: I see no copy in the above code.  Why do you think a copy will be created?  If no, can you explain why what you did isn't good enough?  Ideally a demonstration of what would be good enough in the way the above is not is useful, together with saying explicitly what part of that demonstration is flawed.